Added Variable Plots compared to Marginal Plots
In my regression class, we went over the following problem:
True or false: The vertical variation of the points in in an added variable plot for X2 after X1 is always less than or equal to the vertical variation in a plot of Y versus X2. Explain.
My professor gave us the following answer:

I am a little confused by the third sentence in which they compare the variation of Y on X_n+1 and Y on X1,X2,..,Xn. Why is this relevant to the answer if our added variable plot would show Y on X_n+1 | X1,X2,...,Xn? That is, I thought added variable plots were about controlling for the other variables, but I don't see that in this solution? To me this is just comparing the variance of two models with distinct covariates.
When I saw this problem, I was thinking that collinearity could cause the statement to be false.
